# Как сохранить массив через foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Я делаю авторизацию через Discord, и мне нужно сохранить сервера на которых находится участник.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
        if (Auth::check()) {return redirect()->route("main.index");};
        if ($request->missing("code") && $request->missing("access_token")) {return redirect()->route("main.index");};

        $this->tokenData["client_id"] = env("DISCORD_CLIENT_ID");
        $this->tokenData["client_secret"] = env("DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET");
        $this->tokenData["code"] = $request->get("code");
        $this->tokenData["redirect_uri"] = env("DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI");

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        try {
            $accessTokenData = $client->post($this->tokenURL, ["form_params" => $this->tokenData]);
            $accessTokenData = json_decode($accessTokenData->getBody());
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $error) {
            return redirect()->route("main.index");
        };

        $userData = Http::withToken($accessTokenData->access_token)->get($this->apiURLBase);
        if ($userData->failed()) {return redirect()->route("main.index");};

        $guildData = Http::withToken($accessTokenData->access_token)->get($this->apiURLBase . '/guilds');
        if ($guildData->failed()) {return redirect()->route("main.index");};

        $userData = json_decode($userData);
        $guildData = json_decode($guildData);
        foreach(...)
```

Как мне это сделать через foreach? Не очень догоняю как это реализовать

---Изменил---
Пытался добавить так, но потом уже понял что нужно через foreach, посмотрел примеры, так и не понял как это реализовать

```
$guild = Guild::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'id' => $guildData -> id,
            ],
            [
                'name' => $guildData -> name,
                'icon' => $guildData -> icon,
                'owner' => $guildData -> owner,
                'permissions' => $guildData -> permissions,
                'features' => $guildData -> features,
                'permissions_new' => $guildData -> permissions_new
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "сохранить сервера"?

Comment: @SanyaH Сервер в дискорде, приложил скрин https://i.imgur.com/DgOb4Bp.jpg

Comment: А как у Вас выло декодировать Response в тот вид, что на изображении? Код выше такого сделать не мог

Comment: @SanyaH добавил весь код

Comment: `$guildData->features` - это массив. Вы его так хотите сохранить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** В модели `Guild` добавляем следующее (для автоматического преобразования сериализированного массива в массив при обращении к полю модели)

```
protected $casts = [
    'features' => 'array',
];
```

Код сохранения. Вместо `$guildData = json_decode($guildData);` пишем

```
$guildData = $guildData
    ->collect() // преобразуем в коллекцию для удобства обработки
    ->map(function($guild) {
        // сериаллизируем массив
        $guild['features'] = json_encode($guild['features']);
        return $guild;
    })->toArray();
/* код выше можно и так записать, чтобы не делать коллекцию
    $guildData = array_map(function ($guild) {
        $guild['features'] = json_encode($guild['features']);
        return $guild;
    }, $guildData->json());
*/
Guild::upsert($guildData, ['id']);
```

**Вариант 2**. С циклом, если реализовано через отношение `features`

```
foreach ($guildData->json() as $guild) {
    $features = $guild['features']; // сохраняем список
    unset($guild['features']); // удаляем с текущего набора (очистка для updateOrCreate)
    $entry = Guild::updateOrCreate(
        $guild,
        ['id' => $post['id']]
    );
    // находим ID всех features (подразумевается, что таблица и модель features 
    // создана, а модель Guild связана с нею отношением многие-ко-многим)
    $feature_ids = Feature::whereIn('feature', $features)->pluck('id');
    // обновляем полученные features в текущей модели Guild
    $entry->features()->sync($feature_ids);
}
```

***П.С. Код писал в блокноте, поэтому возможны опечатки***